# @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) taking way too much time for commit transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

> In our application we create new Transaction for our business logic.So for that we first mark **NOT_SUPPORTED** to our wrapper method and then that wrapper method calls actual business logic method which have **REQUIRES_NEW** on it.Now the problem is that when the call come back to wrapper method the diff of time is nearly 40% to 50% of whole API time. Here is the snippet of my code:

### A.java

```
public Object A(){
    long stime = System.currentTimeMillis()
     b.BWrapper();  
     sysout("Time taken by API :"+System.currentTimeMillis() - stime);
}
```

### B.java

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public Object BWrapper(){

     B();
     sysout("Time just after method B call:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
     return ob;
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Object B(){

    sysout("Time before returning ob:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    return ob;
}
```

> So,suppose if **Time taken by API : 1 sec** then the diff between **Time before returning ob:** and **Time just after method B call:** would be like **400 to 500 milliseconds** which is almost **40% to 50% of total time**. And there is no other logic in-between two sysout operation.
>
> > So what is the reason behind this?

Comment: The call to `B()` is a local call and won't even start a new transaction.

Comment: Please provide compilable code. This won't compile.

Comment: This is sample code of the original code.I can not provide the whole original code that is too big.But here I am trying to explain the flow of the original code.And method B() is get called through dependency injection. like **@IgnoreDependency @EJB(mappedName = "JNDINAME")**. Even all the method call whether it is from class A to B or from B to B's method call.They all are using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* logic  behind the scenes that the EJB framework does for you, namely committing the transaction, which can be costly. It is done just after the return of the method.

Understand, that since it is transactional changes inside the business method doesn't really do any database commits, so your sysout's may practically be correct, but the real heavy work is done just after that, at method return.

```
public Object B() {
    //start tx
    doSomeDatabaseChange(); //quite fast

    return obj;
    // commit or rollback tx, may take time
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is really appreciated.And yes you are right there is DB commit time included in total time.But in our particular case I found that at one place we miss to close JDBC connection.So since we are using jboss as a transaction manager,after commit jboss it self going to close open connection for us.And that is where the most time goes.After fixing that issue the time get reduced.And it is taking  around  10% to 20% time of total time.